# Sending images to whatsapp number using c#

Tags: javascript, c#, whatsapp

I am able to send text message to whatsapp number using

```
https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=15551234567&text=I'm%20interested%20in%20your%20car%20for%20sale
```

But I want to send image with this text, but not able to find any way to send using
api.whatsapp.com

can any one suggest any way to do this ?

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/messages/media

Comment: @Fildor Looking for other thing then whatsapp for businees

Comment: I darkly remember that whatsapp denied creating an API for the "ordinary" (=non-business) service. Not sure if that's still true, though.

Comment: @vaibhavshah, Did you found a way around it. ?, If so kindly share your solution, Thanks

Comment: @BJPatel no did not found any solution to it,

Answer (score 1):

Don't think its possible with the public API.

There are licensed third party providers who have deeper integration, including rich messaging formatting and conversational messaging though

Comment: If possible can you please suggest to the top third party player., Thanks